# How can I restore Postgres DB with pg_basebackup in my case?

Tags: postgresql

I have two DB servers and backup which is configured by pg_basebackup. You can see whole command below.

```
pg_basebackup -h $PGHOST -p $PGPORT -U $PGUSER -w -D $backup_dir/psql_base_backup_$(date +"%d-%m-%y") -l "$(date)" -F tar -z -R -P &>> $backup_dir/status.log
```

Below you can see my prod DB which I want to backup:

```
postgres=# \c sks-api
You are now connected to database "sks-api" as user "postgres".
sks-api=# \dt
             List of relations
 Schema |       Name       | Type  | Owner
--------+------------------+-------+-------
 public | clusters         | table | api
 public | migrations       | table | api
 public | nodepools        | table | api
 public | service_instance | table | api
 public | tasks            | table | api
 public | update_schedule  | table | api
 public | version_registry | table | api
(7 rows)

sks-api=# SHOW data_directory;
         data_directory
--------------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/13/cluster
(1 row)
```

Now I am trying to restore this DB for test purposes. I create the same two servers and doing below things:

```
systemctl stop postgresql
cd /home/user
tar -xzf base.tar.gz -C /var/lib/postgresql/13/cluster
tar -xzf pg_wal.tar.gz -C /var/lib/postgresql/13/cluster
systemctl start postgresql
```

But after that I see only two tables in sks-api db. What I did wrong?

```
sks-api=# \dt
                 List of relations
 Schema |    Name    | Type  |        Owner
--------+------------+-------+---------------------
 public | migrations | table | unknown (OID=16386)
 public | nodepools  | table | unknown (OID=16386)
(2 rows)
```

Comment: You're restoring over an existing cluster so the datadir will be a mix of old and new contents. Can you try wiping out `/var/lib/postgresql/13/cluster/*` before restoring and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @DanielVérité I've tryed to move /var/lib/postgresql/13/cluster/ to /var/lib/postgresql/13/cluster_bak previously. After I've extracter tar to /var/lib/postgresql/13/cluster